# Qt for non-UI application?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

I'm looking to use Qt for a non-UI application. It has the potential to run on an appliance, but will start out on the desktop. The UI part (I know, I said non-UI) would be a web server with HTML(5)/AJAX.

I would really only use Qt for basic cross platform stuff like threads, synchronization, serialization, resources (strings, maybe images), internationalization, etc.

Which would be better for something like this, Qt or Boost and creating the cross platform layer myself?

Qt feels a little heavy for what I need, but I want to hear what experiences others have.

Comment: to people wanting to close this question as non constructive: "why?"

Comment: More than likely because OP is asking for opinions, which isn't constructive because it's likely to solicit debate, argumentation, polling, etc.

Comment: Attempted to edit out the parts most likely to get the question closed. It's still a high possibility though.

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the subsjectiveness. I'm really looking for guidance from people with experience in making this decision.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This question is not in-scope here because it asks for recommendations and a list-of-things.  SO is a Q&A site where the Q's are able to be answered in a definitive, non-subjective way.  Subjective questions such as this are to be closed as "non-constructive."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're proposing is perfectly reasonable. 
You want to use a number of features (threading, etc. that you mention) across platforms. 
Essentially you have a number of options, as follows:

Option 1 (Bad): Write your own cross-platform wrappers. You'd be reinventing the wheel, and you probably won't be able to tackle as many cross-platform cases and features as Qt already does. This option also means that whoever inherits your code will have to deal with your custom library instead of a well-supported and well-documented easily accessible library.

Option 2 (Not recommended): Use individual cross-platform solutions for every feature you want, like threading, networking, etc. This means that you (and your successor) will have to maintain compatibility with a large number of libraries in the future.

Option 3 (Recommended): Use a single, well documented, easily accessible library to meet all your needs. Qt fits the bill.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using QtCore (and other non-GUI modules) should do just what you need. As choosing between Boost and QtCore: both do good jobs and sometimes they interleave. But not always.

Qt(Core) offers mainly functionality. Boost offer mainly tools to achieve functionality. For example, you have templates and functors in Boost, not in Qt. OTOH, if you need message pumps and the like, you will only find those in Qt.

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in my opinion it is perfectly OK. I wouldn't say Qt is heavy compared to Java, for example, which is extremely widely used for such tasks. Qt is very powerful, clean, easy and fast. I use it a lot, and I don't know any major drawbacks with it.